# Where to place Thrift generated code

Tags: project-structure, scm, thrift

I am working on a project that is using Thrift and as a result has auto generated code.

Firstly, what are the pros and cons of placing this generated code in SCM vs not and insisting developers generate themselves if the wish the build the dependent software package.

I feel like auto generated code shouldn't be placed in SCM but then again there are shackles attached to having to generate the code via Thrift.

Answer (score 2):

Putting auto-generated code into version control is just asking for things to get out of sync or (even worse) for people to try modifying the generated code.  Both of these are likely to cause you significant problems down the line. I don't know much about Thrift but requiring developers to have the appropriate tools installed on their machines is a pretty minimal requirement.